# Using contains filter in DynamoDB scan with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, filter, amazon-dynamodb, contains

Suppose I have a working query such as:

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName("myTable")
            .withFilterExpression("attr1 = :val1 and attr2 = :val2")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(vm)  //contains values for :val1 and :val2
            .withLimit(PAGE_SIZE)
            .withConsistentRead(READ_TYPE);
```

Now I would like to extend this scan. Suppose my table also has an attribute attr3 which has the form:

```
"attr3": {
    "S": "AAA BBB CCC DDD"
}
```

How can I filter elements who's attr3 contains AAA? Or AAA and BBB?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The DynamoDB [Condition Expressions Reference documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference) is your friend!

In your specific case you can use the **contains** function to search for a sub-string. Your filter expression might look something like this:

```
"attr1 = :val1 and attr2 = :val2 and (contains(attr3, :val3a) or contains(attr3, :val3b))"             
// where :val3a and :val3b are value placeholders for say AAA and BBB
```

But I suspect that what you want to achieve is a bit more sophisticated than can be handled server-side by DynamoDB filters, so you have two options:

1. do the filtering in the application logic (ie. bring down your
   results to the client and filter there), or;
2. change your attribute
   from a string to a list, or string set (if duplicates not allowed)

In either case, you should know that a scan with filters is only more efficient than a regular scan in terms of network band-with (in the case when most results are excluded by the filter). But in terms of capacity consumed a Scan is equally expensive with or without filters. So if you can avoid it, don't rely on scanning your table too much!

Comment: Thanks. With regard to your last comment, supposing you want to search your database according to arbitrary fields, is there any alternative to a scan with filters?

Comment: You could create a global secondary index, but you should carefully consider your use cases and don't try to use DynamoDB like a relational database because it's not.

Comment: The contains operator is described in [Comparison Operator and Function Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html)

Comment: Are the operators case insensitive? I see in the docs they use OR and AND. So wondering.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC the operators are case insensitive